# css(background image style) for button not working in intel xdk

Tags: css, intel-xdk

I'm recently create a mobile app have following problem that 
button din't show background image. I using css to add the background image and it working at Intel Xdk develop design view but din't work in emulator and mobile view.

Here is part of my code

```
//inside <head>  
<style type="text/css">
        .button
        {
        background: url(source/sendbtn2.png) no-repeat;

         background-position: center;
        cursor:pointer;
            height: 70px;           
padding-left: 5px; 
            padding-right: 5px;
                    border: none;
        }

//inside <body>
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="getLocation()" class="button" id="sendMessage" value="[    SEND    ]"  >
```

[develop view print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHgjK.png)

[emulator view print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxmiI.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!=]

Comment: So far I can't reproduce the problem.  I tried your code and put a png file in the right place and I see it in all cases (emulator, debug, built app).  Have you tried looking in the debugger in the Emulator?  If you inspect the button element you might be able to tell why the picture doesn't show up.